# Android - giving pdf to wireless printer

Tags: android, printing, printers

I have one pdf form. Now I want to

1)give this pdf to wireless printer---suggest me how to do this and if possible provide some sample for this.

Is there anyway to support all the vendor printers from my andorid application(means Generalized) or else Do I need to support for each printer(means getting the jar file from specified vendor and using that).

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. I did it using google cloud print. For the code please refer to the link https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

Using this approach, first you'll have to register your printer on the cloud using your gmail id. Once done, you can send any pdf file to the registered printers.